# Booting from USB on Aspire M

Tags: windows, boot

I installed Offline NT Password on a USB too boot from on a Acer Aspire M notebook. When I enter the boot menu, I only see Windows Boot Manager. Is this because the boot image is corrupted on the usb drive? Or do I need to configure the BIOS differently?

Comment: new systems are UEFI, maybe the USB drive is build for BIOS.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Oh, okay. That might be the problem. How would I configure the USB so that I can boot from it?

Comment: the tools doesn't seam to work with UEFI. Try this: http://www.zimbio.com/Password+Recovery+Software/articles/sizSiE6roqQ/How+Reset+Windows+Password+Any+Computers+UEFI

Answer (score 0):

You might need to disable Secure Boot. [How to Enable or Disable Secure Boot on Acer.](https://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27071/related/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xMzYxOTcxMTA1L3NpZC92U21GOFZqbA==/~/accessing-the-uefi-%28bios%29-setup-on-a-windows-8-system)